# how to acquire a google authentication token

Tags: ruby, authentication, token

Retreiving the URL http://www.google.com/reader/api/0/token returns a token, which is periodically updated.  What's required to generate this token?  Apparently, and I'm guessing a, or some, cookies are accessed by Google for authentication.

Here are my results so far:

```
thufir@ARRAKIS:~/projects/curl$
thufir@ARRAKIS:~/projects/curl$ ruby token.rb
<html><head><title>403 Forbidden</title>
<style type="text/css">
      body {font-family: arial,sans-serif}
      div.nav {margin-top: 1ex}
      div.nav A {font-size: 10pt; font-family: arial,sans-serif}
      span.nav {font-size: 10pt; font-family: arial,sans-serif; font-weight: bold}
      div.nav A,span.big {font-size: 12pt; color: #0000cc}
      div.nav A {font-size: 10pt; color: black}
      A.l:link {color: #6f6f6f}
      </style></head>
<body text="#000000" bgcolor="#ffffff"><table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" width="100%"></table>
<table><tr><td rowspan="3" width="1%"><b><font face="times" color="#0039b6" size="10">G</font><font face="times" color="#c41200" size="10">o</font><font face="times" color="#f3c518" size="10">o</font><font face="times" color="#0039b6" size="10">g</font><font face="times" color="#30a72f" size="10">l</font><font face="times" color="#c41200" size="10">e</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;</b></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor="#3366cc"><font face="arial,sans-serif" color="#ffffff"><b>Error</b></font></td></tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr></table>
<blockquote><h1>Forbidden</h1>
Your client does not have permission to get URL <code>/reader/api/0/token</code> from this server.
<p></p></blockquote>
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td bgcolor="#3366cc"><img alt="" width="1" height="4"></td></tr></table></body></html>
thufir@ARRAKIS:~/projects/curl$
thufir@ARRAKIS:~/projects/curl$ nl token.rb
     1    require 'rubygems'
     2    require 'curb'

     3    token_url = "http://www.google.com/reader/api/0/token"


     4      c = Curl::Easy.perform(token_url)
     5      puts c.body_str
thufir@ARRAKIS:~/projects/curl$
```

Comment: "I try to ask a question on SO but it keeps telling me I am not allowed to post images!". Don't do that then! http://www.outpost9.com/reference/jargon/jargon_19.html#TAG494

Comment: Escape code by prefixing with four spaces. Pasting the HTML response containing an image tag will be treated as an attempt to post the image.

Comment: and, yet, there was no image.  Seems silly to me.  Oh well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the Google Reader API Auth outlined [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-reader-api/wiki/Authentication).  ClientLogin is the simpler approach, but OAuth is probably the more robust solution if you want to deploy it for multiple users.  Also using OAuth will save you the trouble of dealing with Google user credentials which should be treated carefully.